# Is this an appropriate place to ask design questions?

Tags: discussion

Is Game Development Stack Exchange the appropriate place to ask questions regarding game design in terms of mechanics?

Edit: sorry, I found a duplicate of this question.

Comment: [Yes.](http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1747/is-the-game-development-se-also-a-place-for-game-design-questions?rq=1)